# Passing longer argument to shell script using docker exec command

Tags: linux, docker, arguments

I have to pass the multiple arguments, some arguments requires lengthy inputs to the script runenv.sh inside docker container which is exceeding the maximum length of the argument passing.

How can i pass the below argument to run the runenv.sh script to execute in docker images int_lnxenv.

```
docker container exec -i int_lnxenv sh runenv.sh -hosts=pchost1,pchost2,pchost3,pchost4,pchost5,pchost6,pchost7,pchost8 -dhosts=host1.domain.google.internal.example.com,host2.domain.google.internal.example.com,host3.domain.google.internal.example.com,host4.domain.google.internal.example.com,host5.domain.google.internal.example.com,host6.domain.google.internal.example.com,host7.domain.google.internal.example.com,host8.domain.google.internal.example.com -dports=8000,8001,8002,8003,8004,8005,8006,8007 -pnumber=35642822 -username=general -password=abcd123xyz -version=12.4.2 -paction=download -hosttype=linux -ptype=default -phomes=Both -phosts= -advanceparam=envparam1:envariable1,envparam2:envariable3,envparam2:envariable3,envparam4:envariable4,envparam5:envariable5,,envparam6:envariable6,envparam7:envariable7 -advancecliopts=testingpurpose
```

When passing the lesser arguments, script is working fine, but some of the conditions require passing this extended arguments which making the docker exec not passing command.

How to resolve this issue of docker exec with lengthier inputs
and multiple arguments ?

Comment: A Docker container normally runs only a single process.  If this weren't running in Docker, how would you pass this information into the process?  You shouldn't need `docker exec` in normal operation, but conversely, the argument-length limits apply generally in Unix and you probably need to pass this information a different way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `--env-file` to store the values there and then eventually create another script that converts environment variables to command line arguments for `runenv.sh` if it can't take from env.